# Why do I get a "no such file or directory" error in this Bash script?

Tags: bash

I have this small part of bash script that gets output and writes/echos the output, but it states

```
./test.sh: line 24: : No such file or directory
```

```sh
while IFS= read -r line; do
    cat  << EOF
  - request:
      path: $line
      method: GET
    response: 
      raw_body: $res
      status: $code
EOF
done < "$1"
```

Why is that?

Comment: `done < "$1"` so does `$1` file exists? Looks like `$1` is empty. `line 24: <nothing here>: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of launching `sh test.sh`, you should launch `sh test.sh <input_file>`, like this, your input parameter `$1` will be filled in.